# Copy Image with UIPasteBoard (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uipasteboard

I recently saw this project in which a user can tap on a GIF from a custom keyboard and they would see a "copied" toolip appear. I have one question:

- How does one reproduce this tooltip in the products [GIF-Tutorial](http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/27c2fb5dfeccbf84ef00ce9e5197ac64/200746978/popkey.gif)?

Could anyone give me some sample code to work with. I understand how to use UIPasteboard and it's functions, but I can't seem to get it to work when I put in the UTI type "public.png" in this function: (I noticed in Objective-c it's "@public.png", but I placed "public.png" I couldn't find a source online for this)

```
 let imageURL = NSString(string:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "png")!)
        var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:imageURL)!)
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data!, forPasteboardType: "public.png")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myimage.png")
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = image;
```

you can find out how this works [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912668/swift-uipasteboard-not-copying-png)

Hope this helps

**Swift 5.1**

```
UIPasteboard.general.image = image
```

Comment: I might need to try it on a physical device. The simulator won't allow me to see my "pasted" image.

Comment: That would be a good idea. There are a lot of tools in iOS that require testing on a physical device.

Answer (score 9):

When using `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = image;` it seems the image is not copied to the pasteboard. Instead try the next code, it also explains how you can replace `"public.png"` string:

```
// The Pasteboard is nil if full access is not granted
// 'image' is the UIImage you about to copy to the pasteboard
if let pb = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard() {
    let type = UIPasteboardTypeListImage[0] as! String
    if !type.isEmpty {
        pb.setData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), forPasteboardType: type)
        if let readData = pb.dataForPasteboardType(type) {
            let readImage = UIImage(data: readData, scale: 2)
            println("\(image) == \(pb.image) == \(readImage)")
        }
    }
}
```