# How do I paste an image programmatically with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uipasteboard

I have a working code where I copy an image to UIPasteboard, but I cannot find a way to implement the PASTE functionality programmatically. Any idea or tip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following piece of code might work. Make sure you are testing on the device.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "person.png")
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = image;
```

based on the comment, you can do it as follows. I am putting here the objective-c code, I hope you could get the idea then convert it to the swift.

```
NSData* pasteData = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] dataForPasteboardType:(NSString*)kUTTypeJPEG];
```

you may find the swift solution in the following url
[Swift UIPasteboard not copying PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912668/swift-uipasteboard-not-copying-png)

Comment: That code only allows me to paste the image into UIPasteboard, what I need is to paste from UIPasteboard. I don't want to ask the user to paste it manually.

Comment: Casillas, can you tell me if this line is the right translation to swift? var pasteData: NSData = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().dataForPasteboardType(String(kUTTypeJPEG))

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

If an imaged has been copied from another application (e.g. Safari) this is how I add it into my app.  I trigger this from a UIAlertController as a UIAlertAction.

```
let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
if pasteboard.hasImages {
     myImage.image = pasteboard.image
}
```

Comment: how to trigger this in swiftui?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may use NSData. It works on Simulator too.

```
// Copy
let image = UIImage(named: "sample")
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1)
UIPasteboard.general.setData(imageData!, forPasteboardType: "image")

// Paste
let imageData = UIPasteboard.general.data(forPasteboardType: "image")
let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
copiedImage.image = image
```